# 9.2.9: Strings To Integers

Tags: python, string, list, loops, integer

I have an assignment that I am stuck on. Below are the instructions.

Make a function called safe_int that takes a single argument. This function should try to convert the argument into an integer. If this succeeds, the function should return that integer. Otherwise, the function should return 0.

Then, use this function in a list comprehension to create a list out of the given list. The new list should contain either a 0 or the correct integer in place of every string in the given list:
[0, 2, 7, 0]
Make sure to print out the resulting list.

Here's what I got so far

```
list_of_strings = ["a", "2", "7", "zebra"]

num=[]
a=input("Enter the number count")
i=0

for i in range(0,int(a)):
   b=input("Enter the number")
   num.append(b)

def safe_int(num):
    i=0
    list = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in list_of_strings]
    print list
    for i in range(0,int(a)-1):
        if( num[i].isdigit()):
            num[i]=num[i]
    else:
        num[i]=0
safe_int(num)
print(num)
```

The requirements are listed below:

- You should define a function named "safe_int"     Success
- Function "safe_int" should take exactly 1 argument        Success
- You should call the function safe_int     Success
- You should use safe_int in a list comprehension       Failure
- You should still have "list_of_strings" defined       Success
- list_of_strings should contain elements that are not integers     Success
- You should replace the non-integer values with 0 Success

I'm having trouble meeting this requirement:

- You should use safe_int in a list comprehension       Failure

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what is Success and Failure?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over-complicating it. This should cover all those bases:

```py
def safe_int(string):
    return int(string) if string.isdigit() else 0

list_of_strings = ["a", "2", "7", "zebra"]
list_of_numbers = [safe_int(num) for num in list_of_strings] # <-- use the function INSIDE the list comprehension
print(list_of_numbers)
```

Output

```
[0, 2, 7, 0]
```

Tip:

I usually try not to let my functions use any variables that are out of their scope. Only use constants (IN_ALL_CAPS) and passed variables in the function block. It will serve you well when modelling classes and make debugging easier.

Comment: If you really wanted to get fancy, you could handle decimal values and round to the nearest int ;)